# What is this wire stripping tool connected to a drill called?

Tags: tools, powertools

In this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/MhNcYeLMzyw?t=760) the poster has a quite ingenious wire stripping setup connected to a drill. Was wondering what that was called and whether such a thing can be purchased?

[image: Wire Stripping Tool]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an intuitively named *[drill-operated (or -powered) stripper](https://www.google.com/search?q=drill-operated%20cable%20stripper)* (slicer). They're also available in a hand-cranked version (which probably existed first).